# Encryption in jsp and decryption in java

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, password-encryption

Please help in guiding the way do **AES Encryption** in jsp and the **decryption** in java.

I have used the following code to encrypt

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('8D6DCF3412625F5427B57CA8F41B2B');
    var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f');

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key, { iv: iv });
    alert("encrypted"+encrypted);

It encrypted but the corresponding decryption in java i am not getting

Comment: it seems like homework or assignment

Comment: it is needed for security perspective . when we send a password from application server if it is not encrypted it ll be visible as open text. So encryption is needed in jsp and the same need to be decrypted in java for proccessing